# Understanding Multiplicative Inverse in RSA

Tags: modular-arithmetic, inverse

Okay so I am reading up on RSA, trying to understand how it works, and I come across this

$ x∈ℤ_p, x^{−1} ∈ ℤ_p ⟺ \gcd(x,p) = 1$

Now it then gives an example, as follows:

> Let's work in the set $ℤ_9$, then $4∈ℤ_9$ and $\gcd(4,9)=1$. Therefore 4 has a multiplicative inverse (written $4^{-1}$) in $ℤ_9$, which is 7. And indeed, $4⋅7=28 \equiv 1\pmod9.$

Now I do not understand how one can simply say the inverse is 7.

Essentially my question is, where has this come from?

Apologies if I am being stupid

Thanks for the help, sorry I do not know how to format properly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that in the ordinary real numbers the *multiplicative inverse* of $a$, written $\frac1a$, is the number $x$ such that $a\cdot x=1$.

Here we're not working with real numbers, but with *residues modulo $n$*, which means (primitively speaking) that after each addition or multiplication we're supposed to reduce to one of the residues $0, 1, 2, \ldots, n-1$.

So in the integers modulo $9$, it is indeed the case that $4\cdot 7=1$ because $28$ and $1$ *are the same thing* when we work modulo $9$.

Since $7$ is something that makes $1$ when multiplied by $4$, it is *by definition* the multiplicative inverse of $4$.

Or did you ask how the author *discovered* that the right number to try was $7$ rather than something else? In this case, he probably just tried all of the possible numbers modulo 9 one my one until finding one that would work (there are only 9 numbers to try).

For larger moduli, the [**extended Euclidean algorithm**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) can be used to find modular inverses. There's a pretty good chance that the text you're reading will explain how that works if you just read on and keep faith for a page or so. So far it's probably just explaining what "multiplicative inverse" *means* and how to recognize one if you come across it. Actually *finding* it is the logical *next* step.

Comment: Thanks, that has helped me understand what is going on here a bit better. I don't suppose you have any good resources that would help me in understanding RSA a little better?

Comment: @Ali: No, sorry -- I learned this so long ago that I don't remember exactly from where, but it probably wasn't in English anyway...

Comment: just covered this in class. You explained it really well! Thx :) +1